# Update multiple columns in multiple rows in one sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-update

This pseudocode (inaccurate SQL) shows what I want to do.

```
update tableA (colA, colB, colC, colD)
select b.colA, b.colB, c.colC, c.colD
from tableB b 
    left outer join tableC c 
       on b.id = c.id
    inner join tableA a 
       on c.myNum = a.myNum 
    inner join tableD 
        on a.newId = f.newId
where f.imported = 1
```

How can I do this in a syntactically correct fashion?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in 1 query ? as you can see here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx

You can't update 2 field for 2 separate table in 1 query (maybe if you try to play with views but still I can't see why).

Comment: I don't have to, but I am trying to update >100 fields so it would be much faster to update it in one query than in many queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET ...
FROM Table1, Table2 ....
WHERE .....


update tableA 
 Set a.ColA = b.ColA,
     a.Colb = b.ColB,
     a.ColC = c.Colc,
     a.ColD = c.ColD
from tableB b 
 left outer join tableC c 
   on b.id = c.id
 inner join tableA a 
   on c.myNum = a.myNum 
 inner join tableD 
    on a.newId = f.newId
 where f.imported = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select *from Dewashish84;

E_ID E_NAME        E_EDUCATION
---------- ------------- ---------------

   100 dewa          MCA
   101 Raj           MSCIT
   145 mohan         BA
   103 ram           MTECH
     5 Sohan         BTECH
```

SQL>

```
update harshad set E_NAME= decode(E_EDUCATION,'MCA','dewa','MSCIT','Raj','BA','mohan',
     'MTECH','ram');

 5 rows updated.
```